# Android java.lang.VerifyError for private method with annotated argument

Tags: java, android, annotations, verifyerror

I have a very simple project that compiles, but can't be started on Emulator. The problem is with this method:

```
private void bar(@Some String a) {} // java.lang.VerifyError
```

The issue can be avoided if annotation removed

```
private void bar(String a) {} // OK
```

or the method visibility changed:

```
void bar(@Some String a) {} // OK
public void bar(@Some String a) {} // OK
protected void bar(@Some String a) {} // OK
```

Any idea what is wrong with original method? Is this a dalvik bug, or?

If some one whould like to experiment with code, here it is:

Test.java:

```
public class Test {

    private void bar(@Some String a) {}

    public void foo() {
        bar(null);
    }
}
```

Some.java:

```
public @interface Some {}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new Test().foo();
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
ERROR/dalvikvm(1358): Could not find method com.my.Test.bar, referenced from method com.my.Test.foo
WARN/dalvikvm(1358): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 11: Lcom/my/Test;.bar (Ljava/lang/String;)V
WARN/dalvikvm(1358): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x70 at 0x0001
WARN/dalvikvm(1358): VFY:  rejected Lcom/my/Test;.foo ()V
WARN/dalvikvm(1358): Verifier rejected class Lcom/my/Test;
DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1358): Shutting down VM
WARN/dalvikvm(1358): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358): java.lang.VerifyError: com.my.Test
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.my.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a bug of Eclipse 3.5 compiler ([Bug 289576](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=289576)) which changes the `private` modifier of the method with annotated argument so that method becomes a "package-private" one. So your:

```
private void bar(@Some String a) {…}
```

in the *.class* file becomes:

```
void bar(@Some String a) {…}
```

The changed method however is still invoked by the [invokespecial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc6.html#invokespecial) JVM instruction, which is intended only for private methods invocations (also for some other non-method stuff), but surprisingly works also for "package-private" methods on Sun/Oracle JVM.
During Android *.class => .dex* translation *invokespecial* JVM instruction is converted to *invoke-direct* Dalvik instruction, which can only invoke private methods and constructors. As the `bar()` method has become a package-visible method, *invoke-direct* can't find it and throws `NoSuchMethodError`.

The solution is to use Eclipse 3.6+, or a javac compiler (through `build.xml` ant script).

Comment: I also found this to occur in Android Studio as well. However, it was without any annotations. I changed the access modifier from private to public, and works like a charm. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that "private void bar(String) {}" is marked fully inlineable by the compiler and never actually created.  Precisely why the reference in foo() then occurs (vs inlining) is hard to say, but likely the annotation screws up the compiler's bookkeeping.

(The clue here is "private" -- private methods are almost always good candidates for inlining, especially ones with void bodies.)